# Por que no me guarda los datos de un editor wysiwyg

Tags: php, base-de-datos, codeigniter

Al momento de guardar los datos del editor en la bases de datos me guarda con unos símbolos y no con la etiqueta ¿a que se debe esto ?

gracias por sus comentarios 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Este es el significado de esos símbolos:

- `&lt;` representa el signo menor que (<)
- `&gt;` representa el signo más grande que (>)
- `&le;` significa el signo menor que o igual (≤)
- `&ge;` significa el signo mayor que o igual (≥)

Te esta guardando bien los datos.

Comment: oye pero en la vista me muestra las etiquetas html , como hago para que no las muestre

Comment: @EdisonSarmiento ¿De que manera estas mostrando el contenido de tu base de datos?

Comment: en la imagen se muestra la bases de datos , pero en la vista no salen esos símbolos sino la etiqueta html

Comment: Por eso... como estas mostrando los datos (código)

Comment: con una etiqueta de angular  <div ng-bind-html="item.description"></div>